# Select nodes from the node in htmlagility pack

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

I have html body and I use this code to select particular piece of code and then, wiht the second line, I try to isolate other elements which are part of that particular node.

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='ts']");
HtmlNodeCollection prices = node.SelectNodes("//span[@class='nobr']");
```

but, when 'node' does not contain 'nobr span', elements are pulled from entire 'doc'; how can I limit this search to selected node only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.//` start from the current node and search just its descendants:

```
HtmlNodeCollection prices = node.SelectNodes(".//span[@class='nobr']");
```